# Difference between torsion and zero divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm not understanding what the difference is between a zero divisor and a torsion element of a module. My best guess is that the torsion elements are "vectors" and zero divisors are scalars. This seems wrong to me, but I've looked over the definitions (Wikipedia) for a few days now and I can't spot the difference.

Comment: Your best guess is right. A zero-divisor is a torsion element in the ring itself.

Comment: I get the feeling you didn't read the definitions very carefully: how could they be considered the same? They're of a similar flavor, of course... but the definitions aren't *identical*...

Answer (score 1):

"Torsion" is more module theoretic. Most often zero divisors are talked about in the context of products of ring elements, but you can also talk about a ring element "[being a zero divisor on](https://books.google.com/books?id=b9Jd4uqEuEIC&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=%22a+zero+divisor+on%22&source=bl&ots=BHFyJhEjct&sig=61hzkpPep2kUfYR1sLOWEVXu1tw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBGoVChMIjLrhv62DxwIVglQ-Ch1eDgB-#v=onepage&q=%22a%20zero%20divisor%20on%22&f=false)" module elements.

The term "torsion" is much more overloaded than zero-divisor is. For example:

- one definition of a torsion element of an $R$ module is that its annihilator in $R$ is an essential ideal.
- or you could ask for the annihilator to contain a regular element,
- or you could always define it as simply "having a nonzero annihilator."